# Implementing only specific Interfaces from a lista when creating an object?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance, implements

I have the Class Word and this class can implements noun, adjective, adverbs, etc.
These interfaces extend another major Interface too.

But there are a lot of combinations that this class Word can have.
For example, a word could be a noun only or a noun and an adjective.

How can I initialize this object using a list of Interface that must be implemented when it is created?

I want to create the Word Act as example.
It could be sometimes verb, sometimes noun.
How can I before instantiate the object, put the interfaces Noun and Verb to be implemented only in this specifically class Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of a given class must *always* implement the same set of interfaces; you cannot customize which interfaces are implemented on a per-object basis.

Instead, you will have to solve this with data: having e.g. a boolean `isVerb` field, or a `Set<PartOfSpeech>` reflecting which apply.